# How can I clear the statusbar text in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, statusbar

I have created a status bar in my project using ExtJS. I want to change the text after clicking another tab. I'd also like to update it based on a time interval. How can I do this using ExtJS?

Comment: are you talking about having a bbar in a panel/window or browser's status bar?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the StatusBar ux you probably want something like:

```
myStatusBar.setStatus({
    text: 'Whatever',
    clear: true
});
```